# Offline GuestBook with Pen-Input and PC-Camera Input

Tags: database, forms

I have a requirement to create a Offline GuestBook on Windows Vista platform. The visitors will use the Lenovo Tablet PC to write their Feedback using it's Pen Input. It is also desirable for the Visitor to show his Business Card at the Tablet PC's built-in Cam to record an image too.
I am thinking about using Microsoft Access for this purpose. Or is there a better and simpler alternative?. If I go with Access, how can I capture the Camera image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial. You need a way to control the environment so visitors cannot mess around in the system, or see anything but the application, and you need a special utility to capture images and save them in the database.

There is no easy drag and drop solution to handle these requirements. Are you looking to custom develop all of this from scratch, or are you interested in integrating some off-the-shelf software?

Comment: I understand the complexity.  Do you know of any off the shelf software?

Comment: No, sorry. I asked since you mentioned Access, and Access can do forms. I worked on something similar long ago, but it didn't have pen input or a camera.